# Java map that keeps minimal values per key

Tags: java

JavaDoc for method put of the Map interface states

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
> is replaced by the specified value.

I'm looking for a Map implementation that keeps the minimal value for each key. So, that sentence should read

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
> is replaced by the specified value if the new is smaller w.r.t. their
> natural order.

Comment: Cant you use `Map.merge` ? `yourMap.merge(key, 123, (currentV, newV) -> currentV < newV ? currentV : newV);`

Comment: As this only affects a few methods, I'd typically create such a map implementation myself, based on e.g. HashMap - normally, that's faster than searching the internet for a pre-existing solution (and then having to cope with another addition to dependency hell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map.merge(key, value, Math::min)
```

If you must, create a class `MinMap` that delegates all calls to an internal map. For more points, use Lombok delegate.
https://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
 if(map.get(key) > value){
      map.put(key,value);
    }
```

Comment: For now, I do it like this. I'm looking for a Map implementation in some "common" library that provides this behavior in general

Comment: You will need to handle the case where map.get(key) is null !